# Run external python script from a main script independently

Tags: python, linux, loops, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run an 'external' script from my main script.

I tried `subprocess.Popen(['python', 'external_script.py'])`

but the external script I want to run contains a loop, so it blocks the main script from starting.

Is there any way to run the external script independently so that the main script starts normally?
(like running each one in a seperate console).

I'm using a linux-based machine.

Thank you,

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: How about the `threading` module?

Comment: subprocess.Popen does *not* block until the subprocess terminates. Is there anything else that could cause your program to hang?

Comment: @Vor No, Just the main script can't continue running after executing the external script

Comment: @Rawing My external script contains an endless loop, this is why it blocks the main script

Comment: @HaTiMuX Just calling `subprocess.Popen` will not block your main script. It returns a `Popen` object immediately after its executed, and the subprocess will run in the background. Can you show us more of your code? Something else must be blocking the main script.

Comment: @dano I think you're right. there was a line in my main script that was blocking it. But still How can I redirect logs of the external script to not be displayed in the terminal?

Comment: @HaTiMuX Look at the arguments that subprocess.Popen takes https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor
It takes stdout, stderr as arguments, so you can redirect the output
For example you can do this:
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'external_script.py'], stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL)
Here I don't actually keep the output of the external script (redirect to /dev/null), but if you need to preserve the output without blocking, then I suggest you look into using a seperate thread.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.Popen(['python', 'external_script.py'],shell=False,stdin=None,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` should work in your case, as this will run the

```
external_script.py
```

independently. `Shell=true` is not advised to use when the command string is an external input.

Answer (score -1):

```
subprocess.Popen('python external_script.py > /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)
```

This will execute the script without having to wait for it to finish.